# Rename package name of web service consumer in domino designer

Tags: web-services, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I need to rename a web service consumer generated in Domino designer because it was generated without a package name (default package), so I can use it in a jar file according to [article](http://www.xpagedeveloper.com/2014/calling-web-services-from-xpages) and can reference in an SSJS in an xpage . Is there a way to rename the package?

Answer (score 0):

Marcus,

<strike>if the class was automatically generated in Domino, you probably can simply rerun the generation and make sure that you have a package name then.</strike>

However I found, when using web services in jar files, generating web service consumers using Apache CXF and the [wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) utility.

I wrote about this here:

https://www.wissel.net/blog/2012/03/webservices-in-xpages-axis-vs-cxf.html

Let us know how it is going

Comment: But how do I mute the package name in the qeb service client generation that the designer domino generates? In the parameters for the generation of the client there is no way to inform this data.

Comment: Right. That name space thing was for outgoing LS. So you are stuck with CXF. More details here: http://www.bizzybee.be/2013/01/23/creating-a-java-webservice-client-in-domino-using-apache-cxf/

Comment: I have read your article and adopted CXF to create a web services client, however sometimes for practical reasons I use the Domino Designer wizard itself to generate the web service client. In this specific case the web service is hosted in a Notes application and was developed in lotusscript, which is why I think it did not generate the client web service with a package name.

Comment: If u can touch the LS side you can specify name spaces there. But that might break other consumers.  For practical reasons I suggest you make piece with CXF 